# MATLAB: How to sort .txt data file with 1000 data points (10 collected each day for 100 days)?

Tags: matlab

I loaded in the 1000x1 .txt file but I need to make it 100x10? How do I do this in matlab?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us some sample data? This would make the explanation way easier.

Comment: Please clarify. There are different ways of splitting the data into groups. Be specific! Provide an example input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reshape` should do this for you. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html

But you haven't explained any criteria regarding what the change of dimensions is based on. So, it may not be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reshape function to do this. In the example below I created a column vector x that is 1000 x 1 containing numbers that ramp from 1 to 1000.  I didn't know what order you wanted the rows and columns populated, so I created variables x2 and x3 with the two variations, you can choose the form that fits your needs.

```
x = (1:1000)';
% x2 is created with one column at a time
x2 = reshape(x, 100, 10);
% x3 is created one row at a time
x3 = reshape(x, 10, 100)';
```